# Pass binded object directly into DataTemplate item

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, windows-phone-8

I Have a collection `Items` of `JSection` objects that I pass to `LongListMultiSelector`. I would like to directly pass every `JSection` into each `controls:Section`. How can I do that?

XAML that causes runtime exception:

```
<toolkit:LongListMultiSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <controls:Section Data="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:LongListMultiSelector>
```

UserControl that contains XAML with `LongListMultiSelector`:

```
namespace Controls
{
    public partial class RemoteHomePage : UserControl
    {
        public ObservableCollection<JSection> Items { get; set; }

        public RemoteHomePage()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<JSection> { };

            Items.Add(new JSection { id = 2, name = "Section 2" });
            Items.Add(new JSection { id = 1, name = "Section 1" });
            Items.Add(new JSection { id = 3, name = "Section 3" });

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

`Section` class:

```
namespace Controls
{
    public partial class Section : UserControl
    {
        public JSection Data { get; set; }

        public Section()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Exceptions that I get:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Unknown Module. and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'MS.Internal.NativeParseException' occurred in Unknown Module. and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Unknown Module. and wasn't handled before a managed/native boundary
```

Comment: what's the exception? Where's the definition and setting of the Items property?

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I've found out that I don't need to set any explicit bindings at all and every `JSection` will be a `DataContext` of every `Section`.

This code works fine and causes no exceptions:

```
<toolkit:LongListMultiSelector ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <controls:Section />
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:LongListMultiSelector>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind any collection as an LongListSelector.ItemSource=Collection
Datacontext of any ListElement[i] will be automatically set to corresponding Collection[i] element.